# How do people figure out what goes where?

Tags: software-design, knowledge-management

Okay so I recently started my career as a Jr. Software Engineer, and after training for a couple of months I feel baffled.

So far I have been following coding tutorials and books to make a web application, but whenever I imagine making something from scratch, it makes me anxious. How do developers know what goes where? How does that guy in the tutorial know exactly which files to update and exactly what property or component to change when he adds a functionality?

I have a computer science degree and I was fairly good in my class when it came to solving problems and writing simple 2-5 files of code to accomplish a task. But real world coding is very different! There are generators for everything,frameworks for every language. My university did not teach me any of that. I feel like all those years of formal education are wasted because real world software development is very different.

Is there any website that burns it into memory about what goes where? I want to be proficient at this like I was while solving coding problems in uni.

Answer (score 0):

Above all, know that it is normal to feel this way. Today there are many technologies, languages ​​and ways of doing things. The advice I can give you is to choose a technology, to read the documentation carefully. If you encounter a problem, search on google, the forums... And finally, take a project that you really want to do, try to carry it out with this technology, this is how you will learn and progress. Courage, developing complex projects can be intimidating!